# jsp page dosent load css when using request dispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, requestdispatcher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uulW.png)so i was trying to load a jsp page when the submit button was clicked when i press the submit button data isent to the servlet.so the page loads but without the css.

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/answerPage.jsp?id=" + id);
                  requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

this didnt work so i tried this.

```
response.sendRedirect("answerpage.jsp");
```

it just gave me the 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code to your answerPage.jsp, I would ensure that you have the css page linked in the html, something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

And just make sure that the css file is located in the WEB-INF folder in your project

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the html and css?

Comment: i included a picture of my directories and css

Answer (score 0):

so i found the answer to my problem.the problem was in the url mapping of my xml file